# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined. Using Angular Material Table and array of data from MongoDB

Tags: angular, mongodb, angular-material, angular-material-table

I'm working on an assignment for my university project. 
When i try to get array of data from MongoDB collection i got an error when i try to load the app page.

**Error detail**

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at MatTableDataSource._filterData (vendor.js:125690)
    at MapSubscriber.project (vendor.js:125647)
    at MapSubscriber._next (vendor.js:150670)
    at MapSubscriber.next (vendor.js:146175)
    at CombineLatestSubscriber.notifyNext (vendor.js:147035)
    at InnerSubscriber._next (vendor.js:145470)
    at InnerSubscriber.next (vendor.js:146175)
    at BehaviorSubject.next (vendor.js:145961)
    at BehaviorSubject.next (vendor.js:145442)
    at MatTableDataSource.set data [as data] (vendor.js:125571)
```

I try console.log(res); in **tabledata.component.ts** the data from MongoDB and it look correct

**console.log(res);**

```
[{…}]
0:
error: "0"
list: Array(7)
0: {S_NAME: "SBOBETH", S_ADD: "sbobeth.com", S_STATUS: "UP"}
1: {S_NAME: "GTRCASINO", S_ADD: "gtrcasino.com", S_STATUS: "DOWN"}
2: {S_NAME: "SBOBETH", S_ADD: "sbobeth.com", S_STATUS: "DOWN"}
3: {S_NAME: "GTRBETCLUB", S_ADD: "gtrbetclub.com", S_STATUS: "UP"}
4: {S_NAME: "77UP", S_ADD: "77up.bet.com", S_STATUS: "UP"}
5: {S_NAME: "DATABET88", S_ADD: "databet88.net", S_STATUS: "DOWN"}
6: {S_NAME: "FAFA855", S_ADD: "fafa855.com", S_STATUS: "UP"}
length: 7
__proto__: Array(0)
num_rows: 3
_id: "5ec4672e44f01dcae82c3dde"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

**tabledata.component.ts**

```
import {BackendService} from './../backend.service';
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {MatPaginator} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import {MatSort} from '@angular/material/sort';
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';

@Component({
  selector: 'tabledata',
  templateUrl: './tabledata.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tabledata.component.css']
})

export class TabledataComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns = ['S_NAME', 'S_ADD', 'S_STATUS'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource;

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true}) sort: MatSort;

  constructor(private myservice: BackendService) {
    this.dataSource.data = [];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myservice.GetList().subscribe(
      (res: any[][]) => { 
        this.dataSource.data = res["0"]["data"];
        console.log(res);
      },
      error => {
      }
    );
}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();

    if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
      this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
    }
  }
}
```

Not sure where the mistakes lies, so any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding you dataSource initialization : `dataSource = new MatTableDataSource;`

Change it to `dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();` as you need to call the constructor of the class definition. It might explain there is no found reference to the array.

Based on the result of `console.log(res)` :

```
[{…}]
0:
error: "0"
list: Array(7)
0: {S_NAME: "SBOBETH", S_ADD: "sbobeth.com", S_STATUS: "UP"}
1: {S_NAME: "GTRCASINO", S_ADD: "gtrcasino.com", S_STATUS: "DOWN"}
2: {S_NAME: "SBOBETH", S_ADD: "sbobeth.com", S_STATUS: "DOWN"}
3: {S_NAME: "GTRBETCLUB", S_ADD: "gtrbetclub.com", S_STATUS: "UP"}
4: {S_NAME: "77UP", S_ADD: "77up.bet.com", S_STATUS: "UP"}
5: {S_NAME: "DATABET88", S_ADD: "databet88.net", S_STATUS: "DOWN"}
6: {S_NAME: "FAFA855", S_ADD: "fafa855.com", S_STATUS: "UP"}
length: 7
```

You can't populate your `dataSource.data` with `res["0"]["data"]` as it would mean res is an object with a nested object named "0" having a property "data".
And there is no such thing.

Just try `this.dataSource.date = res.list` if the goal is to populate your table with the content of the array

Comment: is the list of 7 items being displayed in the Error log the result of console.log(res) ?

Comment: opps, that's a bit misleading it's a "result of console.log(res)" not a "Error log".
And Yes the 7 item list is the result of console.log(res) which is also the data from MongoDB

Comment: ok then i'll update my answer. you are populating your datasource.data with res["0"]["data"] but there is no corresponding data

Comment: At first i try but it's doesn't work, but when i change to
`this.dataSource.data = res["0"]["list"];` THIS WORKS!!!
It was also a mistake in my path that in my MongoDB the array is called "list" not "data". But as for the ["0"] i'm still not sure why it needed.